# Las excepciones personalizadas para autenticación con JWT no funciona (Java)

Tags: spring-boot, spring, excepciones, jwt

Implmenté en mi aoi rest auntenticación con JWT, pero las excepciones que creé no funcionan.

Esto es el resultado esperado en Postman:

```
"timestamp": "2022-06-02T21:56:28.372+00:00",
"error": "BAD_REQUEST",
"message": "Invalid JWT signature",
```

Este es el resultado obtenido:

```
"timestamp": "2022-06-02T22:12:25.698+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "com.onlinestore.app.exceptions.OnlineStoreAPIException\r\n\tat com.onlinestore.app.security.JwtTokenProvider.validateToken(JwtTokenProvider.java:54)\r\n\tat com.onlinestore.app.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:36)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\n",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/api/v1/placeorder"
```

Esta es mi clase CustomExceptions:

```
 public class OnlineStoreAPIException  extends RuntimeException{

 private HttpStatus status;
 private String message;

 public OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus status, String message) {
     this.status = status;
     this.message = message;
 }

 public OnlineStoreAPIException(String message, HttpStatus status, String message1){
     super(message);
     this.status = status;
     this.message = message1;
 }

 public HttpStatus getStatus() {
     return status;
 }

@Override
public String getMessage() {
     return message;
}
```

}

Esto es lo que tengo en la clase GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
 @ControllerAdvice
 public class globalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(OnlineStoreAPIException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> 
 handlerOnlineStoreAPIException(OnlineStoreAPIException ex , WebRequest webRequest){

 ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), 
                            webRequest.getDescription(false));

 return new ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

 }
```

Finalmente, esto es lo que tengo en el método validateToken() en la clase JwtTokenProvider:

```
 public boolean validateToken(String token){

 try{
    Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);
    return true;
 }catch (SignatureException ex){
    throw new OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT signature");
 }
 catch (MalformedJwtException ex){
    throw new OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT token");
 }
catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
    throw new OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Expired JWT token");
 }
 catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex){
    throw new OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unsupported JWT token");
 }
 catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
    throw new OnlineStoreAPIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "JWT claims string is 
     empty");
   }
}
```

Muchas gracias!
.........................................................................................

Comment: Las excepciones que son lanzadas en los filtros de Spring Security no son capturadas por las clases marcadas con ControllerAdvice, de hecho, ni siquiera llegan al `DispatcherServlet`. Si quieres hacer tus propias excepciones personalizadas se seguridad, por favor, créalas extendiendo de `AuthenticationException`, lánzalas en el filtro, y maneja tu respuesta personalizada usando implementando tu propio `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.